# PET game, enemies attempt to break through several concentric sets of walls

Tags: identify-this-game, commodore-pet

I'm looking for another PET game, which I cannot find on various sites. It was one of the earlier ones - it was available when I first got access to the PETs circa 1981/82.

The user starts in the center of the screen and is surrounded by a series of concentric rectangular walls, two or three sets I think. There are gaps in the walls in the four cardinal directions.

Enemies appear outside the walls and begin moving inward. They will bump into the walls and remove a small part of them, but generally attempt to move towards the gaps and then approach you. Over several waves, the slight damage would add up and eventually new holes would appear that they could move through.

I recall that the characters used for the player and enemy were card suits? I think the player was the diamond?

I don't recall how the action between the player an the enemy happened, although I do recall there was some timing involved as you peeked out from behind the walls to make quick attacks.

Comment: Was the game in a maze with random wall that the robots would walk into and get destroyed? Think that was simply called Chase and was by Creative Computing the David Alh publishing company.

Comment: No, that's one in another thread. But it reminded me of this one, which is why I posted.

Comment: Sounds sort of like the coin-op 'Star Castle'.

Comment: In a manner, yes, but reversed. In SC you are on the outside shooting in, and the circular walls rotate. In this you are on the inside of unmoving rectangular walls shooting out. The layout is very similar to Dodgems, see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! Thanks to the excellent PET game database, it turns out I was looking for [Attack!](https://www.commodoregamebase.com/PET/159.html)

Answer (score 3):

Does "Space-Crashers" sound right?

https://www.uvlist.net/game-244437-Space+Crashers

Comment: Similar in the same way that DodgeEm is, but I couldn't find any videos to check the gameplay. Still looking...

Comment: @Maury Markowitz : You can download the program (PRG\Henrik-Wening\space-crashers.prg) from this website : https://www.commodoregamebase.com/PET/694.html and then you can download an emulator on the same website : https://www.commodoregamebase.com/gbdownload/. I haven't tried it (it isn't my bag) but I expect you'll report your experience to us...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Dodgems:

[image]

This was a race car game where you go around and try to pick up diamonds.

Comment: Nope, not this one either. I believe this is a clone of an arcade game of the era, there was a similar one on the Atari called DodgeEm. The game I'm thinking of LOOKS similar, but has perhaps two or three sets of "lanes", not as many as here. And the enemies are moving towards you in the center, and I believe the shoot you.

Comment: Sega Head On — https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_On_(video_game) — is the original, I think.